# Determine Oracle package body memory size

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

We have recently added a lot of new packages to our system, and trying to determine incremental memory usage from a prior version of our product. I know I can get the `sharable_mem` value from `v$db_object_cache`.  However, that will not include all packages in our schema, as they may be aged out.

Is there any way to determine the memory size of a package that is not in the object cache?  And, I do not mean lines of source code (`ALL_SOURCE`), but size of whatever it is that oracle does under the hood to compile/parse the package.

Thanks!

Comment: dba_object_size ... generally parsed_size+code_size should give you an idea. and then you can join with db_object_cache to see what is missing, how much size etc.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you expecting that your code will consume a meaningful fraction of the available memory?  I would be very surprised if the potential incremental increase in memory usage from code would be meaningful unless you're in a rather weird environment.

Comment: That's a good question.   I am not 100% if it would matter relative to all the other stuff in the SGA, so maybe I am worried about a non-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [PL/SQL Program Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/limits.htm#LNPLS018)

> In the shared memory pool, a package specification, ADT specification,
>   standalone subprogram, or anonymous block is limited to 67108864
>   (2^26) DIANA nodes which correspond to tokens such as identifiers,
>   keywords, operators, and so on. This allows for **~6,000,000 lines of
>   code** unless you exceed limits imposed by the PL/SQL compiler, some of
>   which are given in Table C-1.

I remember long time ago with Oracle 8i I "managed" once to get an `PLS-00123: program too large` error. At this time the limit was 64K DIANA nodes.

I think nowadays it is hardly possible to exceed the limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PL/SQL collections, then the amount of memory needed to run a stored procedure is entirely data driven. How much data are you caching with each stored procedure?